# virsh command that displays the cpu and memory consumption?

Tags: virtualization, virtualhost, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, virsh

I want to know if there is a command virsh to display the cpu and memory consumption of each machine virtual. I created the virtual machine using KVM in ubuntu system.

Comment: At a given time or for a period of time?

Comment: Something like [virt-top](https://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-top/) ?

Comment: for a period of time

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The command `dommemstat` can give you memory stats for a specific domain and with `domstats` you can get plenty of stats for all domains or just the specified. You can pass the parameter `--cpu-total` to see the total in the moment.

First get a virsh interactive console by typing `virsh` on your command line and then, once inside virsh's console, issue the following command:

```
virsh # domstats --cpu-total
```

The previous command will give you the CPU stats for all domains. If you have [***virt-manager***](https://virt-manager.org/) you can see live some graphs and other nice stats, and if you want to collect them for a time you would need some other tool, I would recommend [***collectd*** and its 'virt' plugin](https://collectd.org/wiki/index.php/Plugin:virt)

Comment: i tried `domstats --cpu-total` and ` dommenstat `, i got an error such as unknown command for ` domstats ` and and empty line for `dommenstat ` I'm not sure what is the problem

Comment: dont forget to always check the shell/program from which the command has been run... meaning that the command as per the answer was run from within virsh interactive interface. From bash, you would need to call `virsh domstats --cpu-total <domain>` for specific domain or the simpler, without any specifics

Answer (score 5):

Nadya Nux: The command 'domstat --cpu-total' is executed within 'virsh' console, not from bash. So you have basicly two ways to do it.

First:

```
user@yourserver:~# virsh domstats --cpu-total
```

Second:

```
user@yourserver:~# virsh
virsh # domstats --cpu-total
```

Hope it helps better copy&paste to new readers as well :)